# Java - Redondear un float y colocarlo en un jTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, redondeo

Tengo un proyecto en Netbeans basado en MVC. En la parte de la vista "ABMProducto" tengo el siguiente código:

```
private void txtGananciaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    float pv = 0, pc = 0, pg;
    pc = Float.parseFloat(txtPrecioCompra.getText());
    pg = (pc * Float.parseFloat(txtGanancia.getText())) / 100;
    pv = pc + pg;

    txtPrecioVenta.setText(String.valueOf(pv));
}
```

Básicamente lo que hace es: le doy un precio de compra, le doy una ganancia y en base a eso me calcula el precio de venta.

Lo que yo quiero hacer es que ese precio de venta salga redondeado cómo máximo 0.00

¿Que puedo hacer? Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que lo quieres para visualizar como String:

```
String.format("%.2f", pv)
```

Así lo formateas como float de dos decimales

Y en tu código:

```
txtPrecioVenta.setText(String.format("%.2f", pv));
```

Para que devuelva un número con puntos y no comas, hay que indicar el Locale que queremos (por ejemplo Locale.US valdría):

```
txtPrecioVenta.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", pv));
```

Si quisieras redondear el valor para luego utilizar en operaciones aritméticas lo correcto sería usar un objeto `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Me funcionó pero me tira decimales con coma, como puedo hacer para que me lo de con puntos?

Comment: Mira mi respuesta editada.